# Cannot resolve method decodeFile in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap, android-gridview

I am newbie to native android development. I am working on android studio. I have `3 tabs`. One is for `map` second is for `camera` to take pictures and 3rd is for `pictures` in which all taken were to be shown. I have implemented `map` and `camera`, for viewing image i am following this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/). Here in a class i added `Bitmap image = Bitmap image = decodeFile(_filePaths.get(position), imageWidth, imageWidth);`

But it's showing me error `Cannot Resolve method decodeFile`. I have searched for it and couldn't find any solution for it.

Below is my code

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(_activity);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    // get screen dimensions
    Bitmap image = decodeFile(_filePaths.get(position), imageWidth, imageWidth);

    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth,
            imageWidth));
    imageView.setImageBitmap(image);

    // image view click listener
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(position));

    return imageView;
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is custom  method defined in the class (in the tutorial you should have missed to copy a method named decodeFile() )  check again ..

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_filePaths.get(position), imageWidth, imageWidth);
```